# Examples of Calabi-Yau that are birational to each other?

Tags: calabi-yau, ag.algebraic-geometry

I was told that Calabi-Yau's can be birational to each other but not isomorphic (biholomorphic).

But I've never seen explicit examples. Can anybody here show me one?

(E.g. maybe an explicit example of a flop between Calabi-Yaus?)

Comment: What does "isomorphic" mean in this context?

Comment: Presumably it means "biholomorphic".

Comment: Try looking at the paper "The movable fan of the Horrocks--Mumford quintic" by Michael Fryers. That gives an explicit example of a CY 3-fold with (IIRC) precisely 8 birational models. 

Comment: One other small comment is that your "e.g." is really more than an "e.g.": _any_ two birational Calabi--Yaus (as long as they're smooth, or a bit more generally, have only terminal singularieties) are related by a sequence of flops. (Maybe you already knew that.)

Comment: @Artie, Actually I need some clarification here: is "any two birational Calabi-Yaus are connected by flops" true for any dimension or just for dim = 3 ?

Comment: Ah, a quick search shows it is proved for any dimension by Kawamata in 2007.

Comment: temp: that's right, Kawamata proved it for all dimensions in 2007. I guess it was known in dimension 3 much earlier, say by 1990, but I don't remember a precise reference.

Comment: The reference is Kollár, Flops, 1990.

Comment: Motto" Moduli space of Calabi-Yau varieties can be connected by using Symplectic surgery theory. Miles Reid’s Fantasy:“There is only one Calabi-Yau space” i.e "All CY connected through conifold transitions $S^3→S^2$  See my question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262479/connectedness-of-moduli-space-of-calabi-yau-3-folds-by-symplectic-surgery-theory

Comment: See this presentation https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjAmvKjqbTUAhVSaFAKHSFIAnoQFghQMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebmath2.unito.it%2Fpaginepersonali%2Fsergio.console%2FSlides_giornata_geo%2Fgdg.ppt&usg=AFQjCNFsBpcgd80akGwVK4cmwEsk13fiuw&sig2=MLiOByqX5K5cvjOTYYEPxg

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in Lee and Oguiso's paper [Connecting certain rigid birational non-homeomorphic Calabi--Yau threefolds via Hilbert scheme](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703315). This gives a pair of CY3s you want (with additional interesting properties).

Answer (score 4):

Take a quintic hypersurface  in $P^4$ with several (say $n$) ordinary double points. Each of them locally analytically has 2 small resolution. Combining those you can construct $2^n$ global small resolutions. All of them are birational Calabi-Yau threefolds.

Comment: Why are they not isomorphic to each other?

Comment: Usually some of them are projective and the other are not. It depends on existence of Weil divisors passing through all singular points.

Comment: @temp:
Suppose $X$ and $X'$ are connected by flopping a single rational curve $C$ to $C'$.  Since they are birational, the divisor class groups of $X$ and $X'$ are naturally isomorphic, and you can use this to show that they're not biholomorphic.  For example, if $D$ is an effective divisor on $X$, satisfying $D\cdot C = 1$, then its proper transform on $X'$ (which I'll also call $D$), satisfies $D\cdot C' = -1$.

The second Chern class also changes:
$$
c_2(X')\cdot D = c_2(X)\cdot D + 2
$$

Comment: @Rhys Davies: this argument only shows that the birational isomorphism   is not biregular, or that $X$ and $X'$ are not isomorphic OVER their common contraction. Sometimes, manifolds $X$ and $X'$ related by a flop are ABSTRACTLY isomorphic, for example two small resolutions of a quadratic cone are.

Comment: What if I want to find projective examples that are birational but not isomorphic?