# connectedness of moduli space of Calabi-Yau 3-folds by symplectic surgery theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, moduli-spaces, calabi-yau, mirror-symmetry

"**Motto**" Moduli space of Calabi-Yau varieties can be connected by using [Symplectic surgery theory](https://spiral.imperial.ac.uk/bitstream/10044/1/231/1/Symplectic%20conifold%20transitions.pdf).

***[Miles Reid’s Fantasy](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01458074):“There is only one Calabi-Yau space”*** 
i.e "All CY connected through conifold transitions $S^3→S^2$"

Such surgery are very important for study of Hermitian–Yang–Mills metrics under
conifold transitions

A conifold transition is a surgery on a (real) six-dimensional manifold $X$
which replaces a three-sphere with trivial normal bundle by a two-sphere with
trivial normal bundle, cutting out $S^3 × D^3$ and replacing it with $D^4 × S^2$.

[Miles Reid](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.4487.pdf) conjectured that the moduli
space of Calabi-Yau spaces $\mathscr M_{CY}$ is connected after allowing the conifold transitions
, i.e., both resolutions/contractions and deformations/degeneration.

> **Question** :Is there any progress about this conjecture (what about in
>   higher dimension), A reference or information is welcomed . See [some
>   very partial result](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01218081)

Comment: Miles Reid’s Fantasy:“There is only one Calabi-Yau space” i.e "All CY connected through conifold transitions $S^3→S^2$ is originally is due to  F. Hirzebruch